# How to restore the mongo db without backup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have these collections and index files present in /data/db dir:
Need to restore the standalone mongo db before 16th July, we have no backup stored, all files are present in /data/db how can we restore der data before 16th July, any suggestion.

```
collection-0--1930030124829508624.wt    
collection-0--5138667409853774933.wt    
collection-0--7067830708941503295.wt    
collection-0--7947847146613003270.wt    
collection-12--5138667409853774933.wt
diagnostic.data/
index-1--1930030124829508624.wt
index-1--7067830708941503295.wt
index-10--5138667409853774933.wt
mongod.lock
journal/
sizeStorer.wt
sizeStorer.wt.1
storage.bson
WiredTiger
WiredTiger.lock
WiredTiger.turtle
WiredTiger.wt
WiredTiger.wt.orig
WiredTigerLAS.wt
```

Comment: Simple answer :not possible. No backup, no mercy!

Comment: Thanks Domscheit, we have checked with our DBAs and they are updating like all the previous files present in this standalone db only in /data/db dir, we also checked from our end we didn't find in any other location WT files present except /data/db dir ....so if suppose we have all the files present before 16th July in /data/db how can we restore it, also we need to avoid duplicates records with current data in collections present, thanks.

Comment: is there any suggestions.

Comment: If you write "we have all the files present before 16th July in /data/db" then you have a backup! Then you restore this folder, that's it.

Comment: Thanks Domscheit, can we restore using these commands: 1) take mongodump backup 2) take backup of  current /data/db dir 3) mongod --dbpath /data/db    will it restore mongodb old data  if all the files present in /data/db dir.

Comment: as we have to implement directly in prod env.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. If you have the files available, then stop the mongodb process, replace **all** files in `/data/db` (i.e. don't add or remove any of the files) and start the mongodb again. Then you have the data as from 16th July.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried you  are suggesting to start the mongo db with command mongod --repair /data/db to restore the old data before july 16.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236005/discussion-between-singh-dba-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Comment: We need to run all the commands in prod env, could you please suggest the steps.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried,   can we  copy all the WT files of collection and index in local system where i have installed mongod in some other dir lets say /data, and from there run the mongod --dbpath /data  and after that to check all the collecton documments whtjere data present before 13th July in the documents....if supppose restore not successfull, what will be approach, i have taken mongodump backup and current files backup presenti n /data/db dir in prod env.

Comment: Copy the data into a different directory (e.g. `/data/db_restore`) and start a separate `mongod` is certainly a good idea. However, for me it's still not clear what you try to do and what your problem is. If you take your current WT files, then of course the MongoDB will contain the data of today. **Important note**:  When you like to take a copy of your WT files (and all other files in the folder) then you should stop the mongod process beforehand - or run at least [db.fsyncLock()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.fsyncLock/). Otherwise the WT files might be corrupt.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried,  Our DBA team is  informing us that we have all the  files present to restore data before 16th July i.e. older data present in /data/db dir, so  trying to copy all the files  as suggested by you in /data/db_restore in my local system and  trying to run mongod --dbpath /data/db_restore to test after that all collections whther having old data  this will be rite approach rite, so that once confirm will perform the same step in prod.

Comment: For it sounds OK.

Comment: Thanks Wenfried, i have run  in my local system by copying all the /data/db files  to /data/db_restore in my local system using command mongod --dbpath /data/db_restore, it's still running, one more query if suppose any files is not present before 13th July will it be still possible to restore the old data.

Comment: You need all files. If one file is missing (even a file for an index which could be re-created again from scratch) the mongod process does not start.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried, our dba team updating that : not sure that the data was actually deleted or not.
We’ve found that mongodb pod cannot access to data then tried to restore them July 13th . During that process we’ve taken a backup.
have no idea what kind of operation happened for production after that.
create new DB or overwrite them?